# Post php y javascript

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Buenas tardes.

El caso actualmente es el siguiente. Mi aplicación javascript con angular recibirá un post de una aplicación php, para esto se me solicita una url. Esa url tiene un formato parecido: http://localhost:9000/#!/unaPagina/vista.html, sin embargo, al recibir el post, aparece un error que dice 'cannot post 404 (not found)', por lo que he intentado con la url de un webservice en vez de la url de la vista.

He pensado en recibir el post que se hace desde una aplicación php (me enviará algunos datos) en una función javascript (tengo que proporcionar una url). ¿Es posible hacer un post de php y que una función javascript lo reciba?, ¿podría proporcionarme un ejemplo?

¿De no ser posible, qué podría hacer?
Gracias

Comment: estas trabajando el php localmente? estan dentro de la misma ruta?

Comment: Hola sioesi, no, el php es de un sitio externo, de mi lado únicamente trabajo con javascript, y angular.

Comment: Por que usar Angular y Javascript en tu app para la parte del cliente. Dado que usas Angular que es basado en el mismo lenguaje de JavaScript, para mi, tener javascript.js y angular.js es redundante (pudiendo realizar las mismas funciones en una sola hoja de js).

Y ademas, creo que lo correcto seria realizar el metodo POST por medio de Angular para que PHP la reciba y ejecutar la consulta que requieras en la parte del servidor(esa es la funcion directa de PHP, servidor).

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario jecorrales, tal vez me expliqué mal. Una página externa usa php, y es la que realiza el post a mi url (que es la url de una vista.html, donde empleo angularjs). Es entonces que aparece el error 404.

Answer (score 1):

Despues de los comentarios, el error es porque el PHP esta en un servidor externo por lo tanto no puede acceder a tu `localhost`. Debes publicar tu codigo javascript y apuntar desde el php a esa url.

Comment: Gracias sioesi, creo que esta podría ser la respuesta correcta, haciendo post a otra publicación que tengo hecha, me aparece un error **405: el verbo HTTP usado para obtener acceso a esta página no está permitido** ¿cómo podría solucionarlo?